# Cannot Access Disposed Object

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form, which is the main form that the user will work from. When the user presses a button another form loads (this displays a list of customers etc.).

When I exit the customer form, and then click on the button again, I get the "cannot access disposed object" error message.

Any ideas? I'm a beginner at this.

```
 custForm custForm = new custForm();
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        custForm.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Probably showing the code that calls this second form would help a lot

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to learn how to ask properly.

Comment: Probably you need create a "new FormListOfCustomer()" when you click the button. Because the other instance was disposed on "Exit"

Comment: I've added code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple. You declare outside the click method the form variable. This is a class instance variable, meaning that it is visible in every method of the class in which is contained.

But when you close the `custForm`  via its own button, this variable points to a disposed object, meaning that the data area pointed by the variable has been freed and it is available for reuse by other part of your program.

The runtime error says it all. You cannot access this area.

A possible workaround is to check the property IsDisposed and if it returns true recreate the form

```
custForm cf = new custForm();
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cf == null || cf.IsDisposed == true)
         cf = new custForm();

    cf.Show();
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I read somewhere about parent and child forms, is that something I need include when using multiple forms?

Comment: Not sure to understand, but usually you don't care of this relationship

Comment: Is it something I need to read up on or do I not need to worry about it?

Comment: Always better to be knowledgable than to be without any clue, this information could be valuable in future, but, I can't say if this is of any value in your application. If you like then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: That's True! I'll have a read, I'm still getting used to the basics, so I've got much to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot *reuse* an instance which was already disposed (see [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). You have to create a new instance of the other form to be able to open it again.